# basic else if and return javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement

I am learning Angular 1.5 and js at the same time. I am assigning some defaults from notify.js. I have code that has no errors, but I have a feeling the else if could be done in a better way. Also, as soon as I try and put returns in, I get errors. Could someone please show me the best way to do the if else and where the returns go (bottom or inline?). I still always have a hard time with ending the functions and semicolons. I know these look odd but, no errors.

Thank you.

```
 function NotificationService ($scope, $) {
    var vm = this;
    /**
     * @see notifyjs.com
     */
    vm.publish = function (type) {
        if (type === 'info') {
            $.notify.defaults({
                scope: $scope,
                className: 'info',
                autoHide: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            });
        }

        else if (type === 'success') {
            $.notify.defaults({
                scope: $scope,
                className: 'success',
                autoHide: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            });
        }

        vm.publishNoClose = function () {
            $.notify.defaults({
                scope: $scope,
                className: 'warn',
                autoHide: true,
                position: 'bottom'

            });
        };

        vm.publishNoCloseAlert = function () {
            $.notify.defaults({
                scope: $scope,
                className: 'error',
                autoHide: false,
                position: 'middle'
            });
        };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$.notify.defaults({
                scope: $scope,
                className: type,
                autoHide: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            });
        }
```

They share everything but the class name.

Comment: I see, does each get a return then of type?

Comment: What do you mean by "each"?